# How can I use a mixture of array and map in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, dictionary

A short version of my problem: Is it possible to use an array data structure, for example, treats `x[0]` to `x[10]` as a normal array, and some other point value, `x[15]`, `x[20]` as a map?
Reasons: I do not calculate or store any other value bigger than index 11,
and making the whole thing a map slows down the calculation significantly.

My initial problem: I am writing a fast program to calculate a series, which has `x(0)=0`, `x(1)=1`, `x(2k)=(3x(k)+2x(Floor(k/2)))mod2^60`, `x(2k+1)=(2x(k)+3x(Floor(k/2)))mod2^60`, and my target is to list numbers from `x(10^12)` to `x(2*10^12)`

I am listing and storing the first `10^8` value with normal array,

```
for (unsigned long long int i = 2; i<=100000000;i++){
    if (i%2==0) {
        x[i] =(3*x[i/2] + 2*x[(unsigned long long int)(i/4)])&1152921504606846975;
    }
    else{
        x[i] =(2*x[(i-1)/2] + 3*x[(unsigned long long int)((i-1)/4)])&1152921504606846975;
    }

 }//these code for listing
unsigned long long int xtrans(unsigned long long int k){
    if (k<=100000000)return x[k];
    unsigned long long int result;
    if (k%2==0) {
        result =(3*xtrans(k/2) + 2*xtrans((unsigned long long int)(k/4)))&1152921504606846975;
    }
    else{
        result =(2*xtrans((k-1)/2) + 3*xtrans((unsigned long long int)((k-1)/4)))&1152921504606846975;
    }
    return result;
}//These code for calculating x
```

listing those numbers takes me around 2s and 750MB of memory.

And I am planning to store specific values for example `x[2*10^8]`, `x[4*10^8]` without calculating and storing other values for further optimization. But I have to use map in this situation. However, after I convert the declaration of x from array to map, it took me 90s and 4.5GB memory to achieve the same listing.
So I am now wondering if it is possible to use index under 10^8 as an array, and the remaining part as map?

Comment: You can implement a map using a vector of pairs which is kept sorted by by the first value of the pair (the key) and using `std::lower_bound` etc on the vector. This has some pros/cons compared to normal map, but can be faster for small n. There may be a flatmap structure in boost already.

Comment: My trivial solution would be to just write a new class which holds both a large array and a map. If the index you want to look up or store is below the size of the array, use the array. Otherwise, use the map.

Comment: Have you considered making the whole thing an `unordered_map`? If you don't need to retrieve the items in the map in sorted order, an unordered_map tends to give you much better performance.

Comment: I believe you must write `1152921504606846975ULL` instead of `1152921504606846975` to avoid constant overflow, so perhaps you current code does not work as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply write a wrapper `class` for your idea:

```
class MyMap {
    ...
    operator[](size_t i) {
        return ( i <= barrier_ ) ? array_[i] : map_[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

Why not create a custom class with an `std::array` of size 10 and an `std::map` as members and override `[]` operator to check index and pick value from either array or map as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can use [ArrayWithHash](https://bitbucket.org/stgatilov/arraywithhash) library to store your dictionary. It stores dictionary as a hybrid of array and hash table similar to table implementation in lua interpreter.

```cpp
Awh::ArrayWithHash<uint64_t, uint64_t> x;
dict.Reserve(100000000, 0);   //preallocate array part
for (uint64_t i = 2; i <= 100000000; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        x.Set(i, (3 * x.Get(i/2) + 2 * x.Get(i/4)) & 1152921504606846975ULL);
    }
    ...
```

Unfortunately, memory consumption is one of the drawbacks of ArrayWithHash. It pads array to power-of-two size, so array part would eat 1 GB. As for hash table implementation, it is even less memory-efficient: it can take three times more memory than required to storing key/value pairs.